# Python: Slicing a string from specific characters until specific characters

Tags: python, string

I use Python 3.7.4

I would like to know, how I can split a string, like for example 
`0-12+65+89+19##1-23+43+1+2`,
so that I get the numbers after the `-`, between the `+`, until the two `#`,
and then put the numbers (as strings) in a list, like for example in this case
`['12','65','89','19']`.

Can someone show me how to do that?

Also, is there a way to do the same thing, just with the part after the "##"?
Can someone show?

Comment: You should better try this with `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using just string `split`:

```
s.split('-')[1].rstrip('#').split('+')
```

where, `s` is your string.

**Example**:

```
s = "0-12+65+89+19##"

print(s.split('-')[1].rstrip('#').split('+'))
# ['12', '65', '89', '19']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs? This method uses the regex which is suggested in the comments.

```
import re
text = "0-12+65+89+19##"
text=text.split("##")
text=text[0].split("-")
the_list = re.findall(r'\d+', text[1])
print(the_list)
```

The result is `['0', '12', '65', '89', '19']`

Comment: In that case, that would be just `re.findall(r'\d+', text)` on the original string.

Comment: True. I assumed that from his "split a string" that he might be splitting at the double hashes in the context of a longer string.

Comment: Ok, but you need another split. Look at his expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]:  mystr="0-12+65+89+19##"                                                                                                             

In [2]:  next((s for s in mystr.split('-') if s.endswith('##'))).rstrip('##').split('+')                                                     
Out[2]: ['12', '65', '89', '19']
```

will first  split using `-`, then will find a string which ends with `##` from the resulting list and split the string on `+`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use regexes, and have access to 3.6, you can use this:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> text = "0-12+65+89+19##"
>>> re.search('-((\d+)\+?)*##', text)
>>> m.captures(2)
['12', '65', '89', '19']
```

The normal `re` module doesn't provide multiple captures for the repeating groups, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9]+)[^-]')  # find number groups after `-` character
result = re.findall(pattern, '0-12+65+89+19##')

# result = ['12', '65', '89', '19']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do the same thing, if string ends with ##, then

```
s.rstrip('#').partition('-')[2].split('+')

s[s.find('-')+1:-2].split('+')
```

So, in case of this updated question, you can use this

```
s[s.find('-')+1:s.find('#')].split('+')
```

Comment: @JohnPlattenborough updated the answer for the latest update in question